# ASP.NET MVC 4 switch resource file via url parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

I am new at working with resource files and I haven't quite got how it works yet. Now I need to have my application's text available in English and in Chinese. I will receive a get parameter (e.g. lang) and from there I will need to decide whether to use Language.zh.resx or my default Language.resx - That's what I understood from articles that I have been reading. Now I have my View Title for example:

```
 @{
      ViewBag.Title = MyApplication.App_GlobalResources.Language.MyPage_Title;
  }
```

I can't figure out where to check the parameter lang and apply it. I saw articles where people say I should create an action filter and they add stuff to cookies and they were confusing. In my case it might not be necessary as it just has one request, there is no requirement for preserving the state as once the page is loaded that's it.

If someone could also give some brief explanation of how resources work that would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of articles that discuss Globalization and MVC using both session and URL variables.  I am linking both because the session one covers Views a little more in deoth, but the logic for views should stay the same regardless if you are routing (/en-us/Controller) or using a session.

1. [Session based Globalization](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html)
2. [Routing Based Globalization](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html)

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a string lang in your controller, in the controller you should change the current culture, so the only thing you need to do is is something like this

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(lang);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

i suggests you to do this steps via some attribute, and then apply it on controllers.